# Expected "execute[Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom]" with action :run to be in Chef run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

I have two Chef resource blocks that look like this within my recipe `install_packages`:

```
%w[rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom rhel7-x86_x64-linux-latest].each do |repo|
  execute "Enable RHEL #{repo}" do
    command "yumtool -a #{repo}"
    not_if { :: File.file?("/etc/yum.repos.d/#{repo}.repo") }
  end
end

PACKAGES.each do |pkg_entry|
  parts = pkg_entry.split('@')
  pkg_name = parts[0]
  pkg_version = parts[1]
  yum_package pkg_entry do
    allow_downgrade true
    package_name pkg_name
    version pkg_version
    action: install
  end
end
```

How would the corresponding spec unit test blocks look like? For the first block I've tried:

```
it 'executes command' do
  expect(chef_run).to run_execute('Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom')
  expect(chef_run).to run_execute('Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-latest')
end
```

but my Chef run fails with the error message:

```
expected "execute[Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom]" with action :run to be in Chef run. Other execute resources:

    execute[Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom]
    execute[Enable RHEL rhel7-x86_x64-linux-latest]
```

I'm unsure how to fix this, any ideas what the test blocks should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `execute` resources are not run, and that's why ChefSpec does not recognize `run_execute`(, but will recognize `nothing_execute`, I think).

Probably you have `/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom.repo` file on your machine, and that's why the resource is not run. You need to stub the call before the `ChefSpec::SoloRunner` converges the recipe.

```rb
let :subject do 
  allow(::File).to receive(:file?).with('/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7-x86_x64-linux-custom.repo').and_return(false)
  allow(::File).to receive(:file?).with('/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel7-x86_x64-linux-latest.repo').and_return(false)
  ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge described_recipe
end
```

If your `PACKAGES` constant is assigned like this:

```rb
# assignment real recipe: 
PACKAGES = get_user_data_config('packages', [])
```

you can stub it in specs:

```rb
allow(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:get_user_data_config).and_return(<some value>)
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense. Would it be possible to stub the `
PACKAGES.each` block as well. How would test that?

Comment: You don't have to stub it, as every package in `PACKAGES` will generate a resource in resource collection and ChefSpec actually checks, if the resource is in collection. The stuff, you need to stub most often are the guards (`not_if`/`only_if`) and data bags.

Comment: Got it, so there wouldn't be a need to test it I presume?

Comment: No, you should test `install_yum_package(<package>)` for every package in your `PACKAGES`, but you don't need to stub anything,

Comment: Ah yes, but `PACKAGES` is defined outside of the run (we call the Chef build from AWS with a dynamic list of packages). What I wanted to know is how do I stub that (i.e. do I assign PACKAGES to something else)?

Comment: You can stub the method that assigns PACKAGES, or stub the PACKAGES itself.

Comment: Thanks, can you please add that to your answer, i.e. how to stub the followng `PACKAGES = get_user_data_config('packages, [])`. Sorry to disturb!